# CSS Grid like layout functionality in flutter

Tags: flutter

i'm trying to build a complex grid layout in flutter.
i was trying to take a look on GridView and also on flutter_staggered_grid_view package but that doesn't seem to be flexible enough for my needs.

basically what i was thinking of is a grid layout system where i'll be able to split my screen to 2D array and place my widgets based on the array layout indexes (pretty much similar to CSS Grid).

for example that could look like this:
[image: layout example]

is there support for such complex layout in flutter? if not - how would u suggest to implement such layout so it'll be dynamic?